# How to add new rows above a specific row (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
(C5): Top
(C6):
(C7):
(C8):
(C9):
(C10):
(C11):
(C12):
(C13):
(C14): Bottom
```

There are 2 user defined variables, apple and orange. Say that apple=3 and orange=3. The output should look like this:

```
(C5): Top
(C6): Apple 1
(C7): Apple 2
(C8): Apple 3
(C9): Orange 1
(C10): Orange 2
(C11): Orange 3
(C12): Hello world 1
(C13): Hello world 2
(C14): Bottom
```

If apple = 3 and orange = 4, I want the output to look like this:

```
(C5): Top
(C6): Apple 1
(C7): Apple 2
(C8): Apple 3
(C9): Orange 1
(C10): Orange 2
(C11): Orange 3
(C12): Orange 4
(C13): Hello world 1
(C14): Hello world 2
(C15): Bottom
```

If apple+orange >6, then I want to insert empty rows above C14, so that the lines "Apple 1" to "Hello world 2" fit perfectly between the "Top" and "Bottom" rows.

How do I do this? My code is below. However, when I ran it with "3" and "4" as user inputs for apple and orange, it gave me this error:

"Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim apple As Integer, orange As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, lRow As Long, sentence1 As Long, sentence2 As Long, addRows As Long

lRow = Cells(6, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
apple = InputBox("Please enter number of apples")
orange = InputBox("Please enter number of oranges")
sentence1 = 1
sentence2 = 1

fruit = apple + orange
addRows = fruit - 8
If fruit > 8 Then
    Rows("13:" & addRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End If

    For i = 1 To apple
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Apple " & i
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next i

    For j = 1 To orange
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Orange " & j
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next j
    
    For k = 1 To sentence1
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 1"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next k
    
    For l = 1 To sentence2
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 2"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next l
        
End Sub
```

Comment: And what line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen I don't know how to check the line that gives the error

Comment: You hit Debug when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue.

Each time you increment the lRow it shuffles the results down one. So it starts on Row 2, then next run it starts at Row 3.

Change this:

`lRow = Cells(6, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

to:

`lRow = 2`

This is just to get rid of that first problem. You can work on that part later.

Next up we need to record the previous value of fruit. When you click the button again you enter larger values, but you need to know what row "Bottom" was on from the previous click. That way you can shuffle it down before inserting over the top of it.

I can't go through each change, but the other significant thing I did was recording a Macro (using the Developer tab, you enable it in the Excel Options). The macro I recorded was selecting a row and inserting a new row. I couldn't get your code to work.

```
'need a private member variable whose scope lives through out the module or a worksheet (beyond the life of a Dim variable in a Sub-routine or Function)
Private prevFruitCount As Integer

Sub Main()

Dim apple As Integer, orange As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, lRow As Long, sentence1 As Long, sentence2 As Long, addRows As Long

lRow = 2
apple = InputBox("Please enter number of apples")
orange = InputBox("Please enter number of oranges")

'TO DO use strings instead of integers as returns for InputBoxes, and validate

sentence1 = 1
sentence2 = 1

fruit = apple + orange

addRows = fruit - prevFruitCount
If addRows > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To addRows
        'Rows("C:" & (fruit + sentence1 + sentence2 + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Dim rowToInsert As Integer
        rowToInsert = prevFruitCount + sentence1 + sentence2 + lRow
        Rows(rowToInsert & ":" & rowToInsert).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbov
    Next i
End If

'record the previous value of fruit, for the next click as a baseline
prevFruitCount = fruit

    For i = 1 To apple
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Apple " & i
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next i

    For j = 1 To orange
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Orange " & j
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next j
    
    For k = 1 To sentence1
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 1"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next k
    
    For l = 1 To sentence2
        Cells(lRow, 3) = "Hello world 2"
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next l
        

End Sub
```

With the **"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"** I was able to get that error when stepping through the VBA code and manually changing values in the spreadsheet.